# How can I change the value of an element smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('div').html('<p>something new!</p>').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>something<p>
</div>
<br>
<button>change div's value</button>
```

As you see, I've used `fadeIn()` to make replacing-value-operation smoothly. But still replacement happens quickly. How can I apply an effect on it?

Comment: WOW..! After executing the fiddle in my question, I got confused. Why a new separated element will be created *(smoothly)* after clicking on the button?! Odd!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add .hide() before change `html`:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.d').hide().html('<p>something new!</p>').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d">
  <p>something<p>
</div>
<br>
<button>change div's value</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just hide it before fading in:

```
$('div').hide().html('<p>something new!</p>').fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var replacingDiv = $('div.replace');
  
  $(replacingDiv).fadeOut(500);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(replacingDiv).html('changed').fadeIn(1000);
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="replace">
  <p>something<p>
</div>
<br>
<button>change div's value</button>
```